# failed to get value into log message? Kotlin - Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I trying to get a specific value as a log message. But it says `D/TAG: null` Why does it not get the value?

Here's my data class

```
data class CityCodes(val codeNo: String? = null, val city: String? = null, val cost: String? = null)
```

Here's my code

`val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CityCodes")`

In Activity on create

```
        val ButtonScan = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7)
        ButtonScan.setOnClickListener {

            val textResult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView9)
            val codeId = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)

            if (textResult.text.isNotEmpty() && codeId.text.isNotEmpty()){
                payFare()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this@scannerActivity, "Enter code ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

here's the payFare function

```
 private fun payFare() {
        val codeId = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
        val code = codeId.getText().toString()
        val ref2 = ref.child("CityCodes").child(code)
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                val price = dataSnapshot.child("cost").getValue(String::class.java)
                //val price1 = price.toString().toDouble()

                Log.d("TAG", "$price")

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage())

            }
        }
        ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)

    }
```

Here's my firebase node[CityCodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qSm7.png)

I'm new to kotlin so I'll appreciate the guideline from the experts.

firebase dependencies

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
```

Comment: May I know, what version of firebase you use ?.

Comment: @NandaR.M Updated Question

Comment: I think there is still a lack of information about your firebase node, does CityCodes have a parent, and did you already settings rules to read and write true (if not using auth).
And if you trying `Log.e(TAG,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference())` what you got.
Sorry if I not helping enough. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just add firebase.reference into payFare function.

Only changed this line

```
val ref2 = ref.child("CityCodes").child(code)
```

into this

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val Ref = rootRef.child("CityCodes").child(code1)
```

and remove the `val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CityCodes")`

line from activity.